# Serialising random key-value pair of XML payload with jms/serializer-bundle in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, jmsserializerbundle, jms-serializer

Key `randoms` below can contain any key-value pair so whatever you feed (as long as it is in value-key pair) will be accepted. e.g. `<tomato>nonsense</tomato>`. However my mapping doesn't pick them up so I get an empty array for `randoms`. What am I missing?

Note: I listed all `public $randoms;` below I tried. I'm using `"jms/serializer-bundle": "0.13.0",` composer package with Symfony2.

**PAYLOAD**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<product id="1">
    <title>Samsung</title>
    <randoms>
        <review>710</review>
        <popularity>good</popularity>
    </randoms>
</product>
```

**MODEL MAPPING**

```
namespace Application\BackendBundle\Model\Api\Xml;

use JMS\Serializer\Annotation as Serializer;

/**
 * @Serializer\XmlRoot("product")
 */
class Product
{
    /**
     * @Serializer\Type("string")
     */
    public $title;

    /**
     * @Serializer\Type("array<string, string>")
     * @Serializer\XmlKeyValuePairs
     */
    public $randoms;

    /**
     * @Serializer\Type("array<string, string>")
     * @Serializer\XmlKeyValuePairs
     */
    public $randoms = [];

    /**
     * @Serializer\Type("array")
     * @Serializer\XmlKeyValuePairs
     */
    public $randoms = [];

    /**
     * @Serializer\Type("array")
     * @Serializer\XmlKeyValuePairs
     */
    public $randoms;

    /**
     * @Serializer\Type("array")
     */
    public $randoms;

    /**
     * @Serializer\Type("array")
     */
    public $randoms = [];
}
```

**JSON RESPONSE**

```
{
    "title": "Samsung",
    "randoms": []
}
```

Comment: This issue way resolved in [last release](https://github.com/schmittjoh/serializer/releases).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was resolved in [last release](https://github.com/schmittjoh/serializer/releases). Section below works now.

```
/**
 * @Serializer\Type("array<string, string>")
 * @Serializer\XmlKeyValuePairs
 */
public $random;
```